# Proving that the two groups are not isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

By comparing orders of elements , we need to prove that $Z_{8} \times Z_{2}$ is not isomorphic to $Z_{4} \times Z_{4}$.

What I tried :

I observed number of elements of order $4$ in both the groups ,

$Z_{8} \times Z_{2}$ has **$3$ elements** with order $4$ and $Z_{4} \times Z_{4}$ has **5 elements** with order $4$.

In isomorphism both the groups have same number of elements of same order .. Am I right for saying this ?
Is the above proof OK ?

Comment: It seems good approach :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly this is the good idea. However, you made some mistakes. The number of element of order $4$ in $Z_8\times Z_2$ is $4$. The number of elements of order $4$ in $Z_4\times Z_4$ is $12$.

BTW the number of elements of order $8$ seems to be easier to deal with in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach is correct, but your counts are way off. $\mathbb Z_8 \times \mathbb Z_2$ has 4 elements of order 4, while $\mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_4$ has 12.

Generally it would be less work in this case to look for elements of order 8: The second group doesn't have any! You may want to look up the *exponent* of a group, which is the least common multiple of all orders of elements. It is also an invariant for group isomorphisms based on the orders of elements, and allows you to distinguish these two groups (it is 8 for the first group, and 4 for the second).